# Solr category search in not working in Magento EE

Tags: solr, ee-1.14

I have implemented solr search in Magento EE on local server and the category search is not working. I think there is some reindexing issue. I am not able to reindex it from backend. Checkbox option is not available to select and reindex it. Kindly check the attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved.
Here is the process that I followed.

- Installed solr 3.6.2.
- Copied files from magentoroot/lib/Apache/Solr/Conf to solrroot/example/solr/conf
  started start.jar file
- I have reindexed all the data from cmd following [Magento reindex by shell scripting](http://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/magento-re-indexing-by-shell-scripting/).

[image]

- In solrconfig.xml my default search is sku and it is working fine in Magento for spell-checking .

Also solr connection test is successful in Magento Backend.

[image]

Now I'm able to see products in my Categories.